# Reactive Form SetValue for FormGroup Array inside observable subscribe method

Tags: angular-reactive-forms, angular-formbuilder

I am new the Angular but I am trying to understand How can we use Reactive Form and FormGroups array while we use the Service Observable.

My form is very simple, It has list of Articles, where you can select one of them and can edit the detail. It also has feature to add new article.

So, starting of the page itself, It has list of articles in left side and reactive blank form on other side.
Now, this form also contain some of the checkbox which provides the tags for an article.

Now, when I load the page, everything is coming as expected. Articles are coming and reactive form is also loading along with all the tags (un-checked)

When I click any of the article to make that editable, I am getting an error 
"Must supply a value for form control at index: 0."
I tried to change the code little but but with that the new error started coming
"Must supply a value for form control with name: 'articleId'"

So, overall I am not getting what is fundamental issue. Seems like I am missing to give a name to the formgroup but not sure how to supply.

// Global Variables: Called from the constructor.

```
articleDetailForm: FormGroup;
tagFormArray: FormArray = new FormArray([]);
```

// While this.loadArticle(this.selectedArticleId); called on change event

```
private loadArticle(selectedArticleID: string) {
this.articleService.getArticle(selectedArticleID)
  .subscribe(
    (data: ArticleViewModel) => {
      const _a = new ArticleViewModel(data);
      debugger;
      this.articleDetailForm.setValue({
        articleBasicDetail: this.setBasicDetailForSelectedArticle(_a),
        articleTagDetail: this.setTagDetailForSelectedArticle(_a.ArticleTagViewModels)
      })
    },
    (err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
```

}

```
private setBasicDetailForSelectedArticle(articleVM: ArticleViewModel) {
return new FormGroup({
  articleId: new FormControl(articleVM.articleTitle, ),
  articleTitle: new FormControl(articleVM.articleTitle),
  articleContent: new FormControl(articleVM.articleContent)
});
```

}

```
private setTagDetailForSelectedArticle(articleTagsVM: ArticleTagViewModel[]) {
// want to loop through variable and checked only those tags which are available for this article
return new FormGroup({
  tagId: new FormControl(111),
  tagName: new FormControl("111"),
  isChecked: new FormControl(true)
});
```

}

```
private createArticleDetailForm() {
let articleId = 'Dummy ID';
let articleTitle = 'Dummy Title';
let articleContent = 'Dummy Content';

this.articleDetailForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  articleBasicDetail: this.formBuilder.group({
    articleId: [{ value: articleId, disabled: true }, Validators.required],
    articleTitle: [articleTitle, Validators.required],
    articleContent: [articleContent, Validators.required],
  }),
  articleTagDetail: this.tagFormArray
});
```

}

ERROR Error: Must supply a value for form control with name: 'articleId'.
ERROR Error: "Must supply a value for form control at index: 0."